# How to get checked input length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get checked input length please see blow code where I am wrong
HTML Code

```
<div id="main">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox"></td>
        <td>34345</td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<a href="javascript:;" id="getLength">Get Length</a>
```

JS Code

```
    <script>
   $(function(){
    $('#getLength').click(function(){
        $('div#main table').find('input.myCheckbox').each(function(){
            alert($(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"get checked input length"*? Get amount of checked checkboxes or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#main input:checked').length
```

Comment: tag name prefix is not necessary in this case also add type checkbox to be more specific.

Comment: I think adding type is not necessary here because checked selector will find checkbox/radio only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMmX4/)**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert('length: '+$(':checked').length);
});
```

If you have other checkable elements use,

```
$('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `.filter()`:

```
$('#getLength').click(function(){
    var ischecked = $('div#main table').find('input.myCheckbox').filter(function(){
        return this.checked;
    }).length;
    alert(ischecked);
});
```